# Bootstrap3 responsive sprite navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a client who gave me a a psd to slice and put into bootstrap. In the pds they had images for the navigation bar, and their oddly shaped so I made a sprite navigation bar with them. It would be impossible to recreate this with css.

My issue is that they are not responsive in the least. Is there anyway to make them so without having to use media queries to resize them every few pixels?

my html

```
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="about" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="products" href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a class="technology" href="#">Technology</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div><!--.col-md-8-->
```

and my css

```
nav ul li{
  float: left;
  list-style-type:none ;
  text-indent:-9999em;
}

nav ul li a{
    background:url(../img/nav.png) no-repeat;
  display: block;
}

.about{
  background-position:0px 0px;  
  width:25em;  
  height:5em;  
}

.products{
  background-position:-25em 0;  
  width:9em;  
  height:5em;  
}

.technology{
  background-position:-34em 0;  
  width:13em;  
  height:5em;  
}
```

I have tried adding `min-height` and `min-width` to them, but it seemed to have no effect.

Comment: If you must use an image then try using relative units `%` for the background position values to make it responsive. Would be interesting to see what you're working on, can you share the image with us?

Comment: I tried percents for background position, but it just gets rid of the image completely. It really seems to be more of a problem with the width and height. And unfortunately I cannot share the image because of a confndenciality agreement I signed.